# Change vertical cell size space created with a XIB file

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I change the space between the cells? It currently looks like this:

[image]

Nothing that I've tried works, this is my current setup:

[image]

and this is where I'm defining the cell:

```
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        return products.count
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // This determines the size of the cell on the featured slider
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 350)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeaturedPostsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeaturedPostsCollectionViewCell
        let product = products[indexPath.row]
        cell.featuredImage.image = UIImage(named: "4")
        cell.lbName.text = product.Name!
        cell.lbDesc.text = product.desc!

        return cell
    }
```

I've looked around but can't find what is it that is giving it so much space...

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, it happened that I had to fix the width to my preferred value:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 310, height: 350)
}
```